# Boost Spirit debug enum class (c++11) compile error

Tags: boost, c++11, enums, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to debug a simple struct which contains an enum class with BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE, but I always get the compile error "C:\boost\boost\spirit\home\support\attributes.hpp:1226: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&' near 'out << val;'"

I don't know why I get a rvalue error like that, I tried to to add a manual overload for the operator<< for the enum class but that didn't work either.

I am using boost 1.55 and try to compile with gcc 4.8 with MinGW 32-bit on Windows 8.1 x64.

When I change the enum class to a default c++ enum it works, but I'd like to use the new enum classes for proper namespace handling.

Comment: You get "rvalues like that" just because the compiler will typically list all candidate overloads of `operator<<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know why I get a rvalue error like that, I tried to to add a manual overload for the operator<< for the enum class but that didn't work either.

I think that required code, since that *does* work:

1. First, with a *classic enum* **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ffb2787f5849405)**

   ```
   #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

   struct data_t
   {
       std::string label;
       enum Choice { left, right, up, down } choice;

       data_t(std::string label="default", Choice choice=left): label(std::move(label)), choice(choice) {}

       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Choice const& v) {
           switch(v) { 
               case left: return os << "left";
               case right:return os << "right";
               case up:   return os << "up";
               case down: return os << "down";
               default:   return os << "?";
           }
       }
       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, data_t const& v) {
           return os << "{label:" << v.label << ";choice:" << v.choice << "}";
       }
   };


   template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
       struct parser : qi::grammar<It, data_t(), Skipper>
   {
       parser() : parser::base_type(start)
       {
           using namespace qi;

           choice_.add
               ("left",  data_t::left)
               ("right", data_t::right)
               ("up",    data_t::up)
               ("down",  data_t::down);

           start %= as_string[ lexeme[+graph] ] >> lexeme [choice_];

           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
       }

   private:
       qi::symbols<char, data_t::Choice> choice_;
       qi::rule<It, data_t(), Skipper> start;
   };

   bool doParse(const std::string& input)
   {
       typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
       auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

       parser<It, qi::space_type> p;
       data_t data;

       try
       {
           bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data);
           if (ok)   
           {
               std::cout << "parse success\n";
               std::cout << "data: " << data << "\n";
           }
           else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

           if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
           return ok;
       } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
       {
           std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
           std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
       }

       return false;
   }

   int main()
   {
       bool ok = doParse("label1 up");
       return ok? 0 : 255;
   }
   ```
2. Second with an *enum class* **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff51abee6f50ae8d)**

   ```
   #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

   struct data_t
   {
       std::string label;
       enum class Choice { left, right, up, down } choice;

       data_t(std::string label="default", Choice choice=Choice::left): label(std::move(label)), choice(choice) {}

       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Choice const& v) {
           switch(v) { 
               case Choice::left: return os << "left";
               case Choice::right:return os << "right";
               case Choice::up:   return os << "up";
               case Choice::down: return os << "down";
               default:   return os << "?";
           }
       }
       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, data_t const& v) {
           return os << "{label:" << v.label << ";choice:" << v.choice << "}";
       }
   };


   template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
       struct parser : qi::grammar<It, data_t(), Skipper>
   {
       parser() : parser::base_type(start)
       {
           using namespace qi;

           choice_.add
               ("left",  data_t::Choice::left)
               ("right", data_t::Choice::right)
               ("up",    data_t::Choice::up)
               ("down",  data_t::Choice::down);

           start %= as_string[ lexeme[+graph] ] >> lexeme [choice_];

           BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
       }

   private:
       qi::symbols<char, data_t::Choice> choice_;
       qi::rule<It, data_t(), Skipper> start;
   };

   bool doParse(const std::string& input)
   {
       typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
       auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

       parser<It, qi::space_type> p;
       data_t data;

       try
       {
           bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data);
           if (ok)   
           {
               std::cout << "parse success\n";
               std::cout << "data: " << data << "\n";
           }
           else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

           if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
           return ok;
       } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
       {
           std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
           std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
       }

       return false;
   }

   int main()
   {
       bool ok = doParse("label1 up");
       return ok? 0 : 255;
   }
   ```

My guess is you forgot to add serialization to either your enum **or** your struct.

Comment: thanks that worked. I tried to define the operator<< outside of the struct but still got the same error. I think I have to use it like that with frend but thats fine. :)

Comment: @Xander your problem then will have been that the operator wasn't visible at the time. Two reasons: it was declared after the relevant instantiations _or_ outside the namespace that defined the `struct` or the `enum class`. In fact, the latter seems likely to me.